# Return value in Jquery Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am working on jquery ajax. I am using the code as follow :

```
var url = baseurl +"/index.php/users/ajaxwixusers";
    var dataStringfirst = 'wixuserid='+ instanceId;
    $.ajax({
            //dataType : 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            url : url,
            data : dataStringfirst,
            complete : function() { },
            success: function(data) 
                    {
                        alert(data);
                        window.location.href="http://localhost:81/customers/index.php/acappointments/appointuseroverlay/user_id/203";
                    }
        });
```

In PHP file I am getting the value as :

```
echo $user_id = $wixuser->id;
```

I want to return ths value on success. When I am trying to alert the output of ajax.

It is returning the complete HTML of the file. How can I return only value instead of complete HTML?

Comment: when I use json then nothing returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returned complete HTML because your app kept running and rendering the rest of the request after your echo command. You should add one line exit instead.

```
exit();
```

Comment: in php or ajax complete ?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax response always gives complete data as output from requested page  and If you don't want to use HTML then why you are placing it there? If you want to get any specific value then Print that value only don't use HTML on that page.

Comment: Do you have any idea that what you are saying, see Telvin's answer